# configuring postfix to catch all with a suffix using virtual alias map

Tags: postfix

I'm having problems trying to configure a catch all email in postfix.

I have an email account `messages@example.com`. All emails sent to this address are piped to a php script.

What I would like to do is forward all emails in the format `anything.messages@example.com`, e.g. `3454534.messages@example.com` and `dsf843fdd.messages@example.com`, to this email account.

After doing some research I've done the following but to no avail.

In /etc/postfix/main.cf I have added the line

```
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

In /etc/postfix/virtual I have added

```
/.*messages@example.com   messages
```

Any help is appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nowhere is it documented that hash maps support this kind of wildcarding - you're probably thinking about regexp or PCRE tables:

http://www.postfix.org/PCRE_README.html
http://www.postfix.org/pcre_table.5.html

Something like this should work:

/etc/postfix/wildcard.pcre:
`/^\d+\.message@example\.com$/ message`

Note that PCRE maps are not compiled; don't run `postmap` on them.

However, I would strongly suggest you switch to using recipient delimiters instead; it makes all of this unnecessary.

Comment: Actually, `\d+` will only match digits and the user wants to match everything so `\w+` should be used. Also, a quick way to check it's working is by using `postmap` (yes it works) like that: `postmap -q 'foo.messages@example.com' pcre:/etc/postfix/wildcard.pcre`

Comment: @adaptr Thanks for your response. I've created wildcare.pcre as suggests and run the command above, but it returns nothing. Do I take that as a sign it is working? Do I need to reference the pcre table in main.cf?

Comment: ...yes, obviously. Just add it at the end of your virtual_alias_maps config: virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual, pcre:/etc/postfix/wildcard.pcre

Comment: Nothing seems to be happening. messages@example.com are still being routed, but foo.messages@example.com aren't, nor are they being returned to sender. I've tried checking the maillog but for some reason it hasn't updated since this morning, probably another issue entirely

Comment: my bad, i missed the backslash escape on the .com. Seems to be working great, thanks!